# My old mouse for my old computer is broken. Where can I get another one or an adapter?

Tags: mouse

I have an old computer with the mouse not working because the cable connector is broken on the mouse. The mouse connection is directly on the computer, not on the keyboard.  The mouse connection(which is broken) on the mouse has 6 round pins and 1 flat pin. Where can I get an old mouse or an adapter from a USB mouse to the computer?

Comment: That's what's known as a "PS/2" mouse.  Use that term in Google and you will probably find a few hits (though read carefully, as often the people writing the ads don't know what "PS/2" means in this context.)  Or (a bit more practically) you can get an adapter to adapt a USB mouse to the PS/2 connector.

Comment: Here is one that's straight-up PS/2, with a photo of the connector:  http://www.quill.com/corded-optical-mice/cbs/348491.html?cm_mmc=SEM_PLA_T_348491

Comment: @Scott How about a PCI add-in card that gives you 2 or more USB ports? Is there a reason this is not done?

Comment: This computer already has 4 USB ports but my USB mouse doesn't work with them. I don't know much about adding a PCI card. Would this make the proposed USB connections workable with a mouse?

Answer (score 2):

What your mouse has is PS/2 connector (Green):

[image: PS2]

You can search for what you need now that you know (PS/2 mouse).

If you have a USB mouse, you can convert it to PS/2 with a usb to ps/2 adaptor:

[image: usb to ps2 converter]

Again, you can search for a place to purchase for your particular area of the world.

Comment: Small addition: This will work **iff** (if and only if) you have a mouse which understands both the USB and the PS/2 protocols. That used to be common, but do not expect it to work if you get a new mouse.

Comment: In general, a good rule of thumb is just to get a mouse with one of those if you can ;)

Answer (score 1):

A few PC shops in my area often have bargain bins for PS/2 keyboards and mice (albeit grotty, and yellowed from bromine flame retarding plastics). If they don't have them out front, ask them. Chances are they have one sitting around cluttering up space, that they would be willing to flog for a couple bucks.